# How to open my broswer in my rss reader instead of my default one? Android

Tags: android, webview, rss

I have created a RSS Reader application and when I click on a news it opens my default mobile browser and loads the link. But I want it to open my another activity that has a WebView and so it can load it there.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
    RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is what happens when a news is clicked. I just want it to pass that link to a new WebView and load it there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better if you pass the url to your browser activity and then launch it as a second activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentClass.this, YourWebViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("url", item.getLink());
startActivity(intent)
```

Then in the WebView Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String link = extras.getString("url");
}
```

and load the url in your WebView

Uri to String

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
stringUri = uri.toString();
```

String to Uri

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
```

Comment: try: Intent intent = new Intent(currentClass.this, YourWebViewActivity.class);